# How to redirect xampp apache log button

Tags: xampp

I set daily error.log and access.log in httpd.conf

```
ErrorLog "|D:/xampp/apache/bin/rotatelogs.exe D:/xampp/apache/logs/error%y_%m_%d.log 86400 480"
CustomLog  "|D:/xampp/apache/bin/rotatelogs.exe D:/xampp/apache/logs/access%y_%m_%d.log 86400 480" combined
```

How can I open today's log: access21_02_23.log when I click log button at xampp panel?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the hardlink for the file.

`hardlink.bat`

```
set dd=%date:~8,2%
set dm=%date:~5,2%
set dy=%date:~2,2%
set mydate=%dy%_%dm%_%dd%
del D:\xampp\apache\logs\access.log
mklink /H D:\xampp\apache\logs\access.log D:\xampp\apache\logs\access%mydate%.log
del D:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log
mklink /H D:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log D:\xampp\apache\logs\error%mydate%.log
```